# SQL search in multiple column with multiple keywords

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a front-end form with two fields named "name" and "location". In my database I've a table named "postmeta" with columns (meta_id, meta_key, meta_value). When a user submits the front-end form I want to search both fields values in this table. The "name" field will look value within "meta_value" where "meta_key" is equal to "company_name", similiaryly, the "location" field will look it's value within same "meta_value" column but where "meta_key" is equal to "company_location".

In the end when results are final, I want it to group data by "meta_value" field provided "meta_key" is equal to "company_name" only.

I've managed to generate an SQL query like this.

```
SELECT meta_value FROM postmeta
 WHERE (meta_key = 'company_name' AND meta_value LIKE '%apple%')
 OR (meta_key = 'company_location' AND meta_value LIKE '%paris%')
 GROUP BY meta_value
 ORDER BY meta_value
```

I want all results where company name contains the keyword e.g. "apple" AND company location contains the keyword e.g. "paris", but GROUP results only by company name.

Comment: Both conditions can not be true at the same time when evaluating row by row. How do you correlate the two keys if there are thousands of meta_keys with a value of 'company_name'?

Comment: Yeah, I agree, there should be OR operator instead of AND, I've edited the query above.